# ByBit Api: how can i get all tokens tp/sl orders

Tags: bybit, python-bybit

I know that there is an option to get an order book in the api, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I need to get the exact number of all take profit and stop loss through the bybit api

Is it possible to implement this and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Brave's Leo suggested this:

```
import requests

api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"

url = f"https://api.bybit.com/v3/public/orders?symbol=BTCUSDT&apikey={api_key}"

response = requests.get(url)

orders = response.json()

take_profit_orders = [order for order in orders if order["status"] == "takeProfit"]

stop_loss_orders = [order for order in orders if order["status"] == "stopLoss"]

print(f"Take profit orders: {len(take_profit_orders)}") print(f"Stop loss orders: {len(stop_loss_orders)}")
```

This code will retrieve all open orders for the BTCUSDT symbol using the Bybit API, and then filter the results to only include orders with the appropriate status. The `len()` function is used to get the length of each list, which gives us the exact number of take profit and stop loss orders.

Comment: Your code doesn't work
There is no such endpoint in the api, besides such status as takeProfit or stopLoss is also absent